# "Внимательные к миру и к друг к другу" - какое "к" лишнее?

Tags: предлоги

> Несомненно, я вызвала неудовольствие достопочтенного синьора, но в ту
>   же секунду оправдала себя тем, что всё же мы не на великосветском
>   приёме и не на красной дорожке. Хотя их пара безусловно заслуживала
>   приз! Очень-очень взрослые, но такие ухоженные, **внимательные к миру
>   и к друг к другу**, не растерявшие интереса и вкуса к жизни! Истинные
>   неторопливые римляне, которых мы зовём между собой «транквилло»; их
>   здесь много раскидано по площадям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сказал ***внимательные к миру и друг к другу***. Хотя бы потому, что *"к друг другу"* в принципе не говорят по-хорошему.

Comment: Угу. А симметрию "внимательны к... и к..." сохранить никак невозможно?

Comment: Не знаю, по-моему, невозможно. Посмотрим, что остальные скажут.

Comment: По-моему очевидно. "Друг к другу" не может быть самостоятельным дополнением, управляемым предлогом. Первое "Друг" вообще стоит а именительном падеже, носитель русского просто не может поставить предлог перед ним.

О какой симметрии тут идет речь?

Answer (score 3):

В большом толковом словаре:
[2. **ДРУГ**.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?ab=x&az=x&bts=x&lop=x&lv=x&word=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3&zar=x) **Друг друга; друг другу; друг другом; друг о друге; друг на друга и т. п.** *(разг.)* **друг дружку; друг дружке; друг о дружке; друг за дружку и т. п.** *(устар. **кратк.*** к другой). Взаимно один другого, один другому, один другим и т. п.; один других, одни другим и т. п. *Вспоминать друг о друге. Забыть друг друга. Остались довольны друг другом. Оказались в двух шагах друг от друга. Хвастались успехами друг перед другом. Жаловались друг на друга. Живут далеко друг от друга. Друг в друге души не чают* (очень дорожат друг другом).

Первая "к" лишняя. Ошибка возникает тогда, когда указанное словосочетание безосновательно наделяют свойством неразрывности. Более того, по той же причине его нередко пишут через дефис: "друг-друга", "друг-другу".
На самом деле предлог при его наличии всегда располагается посередине конструкции: *друг **к** другу, друг **от** друга, друг **с** другом* и так далее.

*Дворовые, человек восемь, своровав у боярина сальную свечу, хлестали засаленными картами по столу, — отыгрывали **друг у друга** копейки* (А. Толстой).
*Они бросились невольно **друг к другу**, но остановились и глядели **друг на друга** с улыбкой, влажными глазами и не могли ничего сказать* (И. А. Гончаров).